# Adjustment in risk_table function

Tags: gtsummary

On the website, https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/ggsurvfit/reference/add_risktable.html, there is the following example:

```
p <-
   survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, date = df_lung) %>%
   ggsurvfit() +
   add_censor_mark() +
   add_confidence_interval()

# using the function defaults
p + add_risktable()
```

See that the result is presented **divided into two groups: male and female, in addition to At risk and Events**.

In the work I am developing, cumulative incidence (CIF), I need to use a similar expression (number 1 instead of "sex"). It would be something like:

```
p <-
   cuminc(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = df_lung) %>%
   ggcuminc() +
   add_censor_mark() +
   add_confidence_interval()

# using the function defaults
p + add_risktable()
```

Where, status would be: 1 death and 2 non-cancer death

I tried to follow the examples, but they all have `"sex"`.
I would like to know how I could use the examples considering `"1"`, that is, **the result divided into two groups based on the status (1 death and 2 deaths not related to cancer), in addition to At risk and Events**. When I run, there is no separation of groups.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to create. All the functions work with stratified models (ie with sex) and unstratified (those with the 1).

Comment: I'll rephrase my question, but I want to use the non-stratified model for CIF